# Why is Google custom search not indexing my PageMap data?

Tags: google-custom-search, structured-data

As a proof of concept I have set up a static page with the content below following the same pattern as an example in
[Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_data)

I have created a Google custom search on the url of this page. However,
custom search shows 0 results. On the custom search console it also shows me,
Total indexed 0.
There are no crawl errors.
I have waited over 24 hours.
I have also requested google to index the site under the crawl options.
What do I need to do to be able to set up a page that will be indexed in my custom search with custom data types?

```html
<html>
  <head>
   <!--
  <PageMap>
     <DataObject type="book">
        <Attribute name="title">The Biomechanics of a Badminton
        Smash</Attribute>
        <Attribute name="author">Avelino T. Lim</Attribute>
        <Attribute name="description">The smash is the most
        explosive and aggressive stroke in Badminton. Elite athletes can
        generate shuttlecock velocities of up to 370 km/h. To perform the
        stroke, one must understand the biomechanics involved, from the body
        positioning to the wrist flexion. </Attribute>
        <Attribute name="page_count">25</Attribute>
        <Attribute name="rating">4.5</Attribute>
        <Attribute name="last_update">05/05/2009</Attribute>
  <Attribute name="isbn">9999999999</Attribute>
  <Attribute name="lexile">123</Attribute>
  <Attribute name="library">ls</Attribute>
  <Attribute name="library">kpmid</Attribute>
     </DataObject>
  <DataObject type="book">
        <Attribute name="title">The Biomechanics of a Badminton
        Smash2</Attribute>
        <Attribute name="author">Avelino T. Lim</Attribute>
        <Attribute name="description">The smash is the most
        explosive and aggressive stroke in Badminton. Elite athletes can
        generate shuttlecock velocities of up to 370 km/h. To perform the
        stroke, one must understand the biomechanics involved, from the body
        positioning to the wrist flexion. </Attribute>
        <Attribute name="page_count">25</Attribute>
        <Attribute name="rating">4.5</Attribute>
        <Attribute name="last_update">05/05/2009</Attribute>
  <Attribute name="isbn">99999999992</Attribute>
  <Attribute name="lexile">123</Attribute>
  <Attribute name="library">ls</Attribute>
  <Attribute name="library">kpmid</Attribute>
     </DataObject>
    
  </PageMap>
  -->
  </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```